# Why 1,000 bytes isn't enough to make 1 Kilobyte?

Tags: computer-science

(Ignoring the difference between kibibyte and kilobyte)

When grouping bytes, why it takes 1024 bytes to make 1 Kilobyte? Why 1,000 bytes isn't enough?

Or,

Why we always group bits in a power of 2? Why not group them in the power of 10?

Comment: Useful read : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: Depends on who you ask, and how they did the math. A kilobyte is 1000 bytes in SI units, and 1024 is called a kibibyte. Others might simply call 2^10 a kilobyte.

Comment: @nos yes, but my question is why we always group using the power of 2? Why not we group bits using some other number?

Comment: @iamcreasy Well, we don't always, we either use a decimal base (so one kilobyte means 1000), or we use a binary base (so one kilobyte means 1024, though that's supposed to be called a kibibyte). A decimal base makes sense because that's what our normal numbers use, a binary base makes sense because computers work in base 2 (they only deal with the digits 0 and 1).

Comment: Computers have 2 fingers, we have 10 fingers. That's why.

Comment: @N.B. What an elegant answer

Answer (score 2):

Everything in computers is either 0 or 1.There are only 2 numbers. 2^10 is 1024.

There is no number x such that 2^x would be 1000.

Comment: But why we always have to group bits in a power of 2? Why not select bit using power of 10? or something else.

Comment: A machine can only understand 2 signals 'on' or 'off' , here 0 represent off and 1 represent on. That is why 2 used.

Comment: i think you mean that 10 ^ 1010 is 10000000000 - given that there are only 10 numbers 0 and 1. and of course 2 ^ 3 is 1000

Comment: @Golden_flash Yes, buy why use 2 when grouping the signals? Why don't we group 10 signals, or 100 signals?

Comment: @pm100               2^3 is 8 and you are converting it to binary, 10^11 is 1000 would be they way to represent it in binary but how can you keep left side integral and right side binary ? There is no integral number x such that 2^x is 1000.

Comment: @iamcreasy we can have that we can make a 100 bit register by clubbing 2^6+2^5+2^2,some of the floating-point units in processors have 80 bit register.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in computers can only be 1 (on) or 0 (off).

In real life this translates to something like for example: >2 Volts is a 1 and < 1 volt is a 0, and it should never be between 1 and 2.

Theoretically, we can use higher bases like base 10, or any other base for that matter. In fact you can have potentially near infinite amount of bases (i.e. using analog instead of digital signals). But in practice it just doesn't work that well in computer architectures due to signal degradation.

Taken from http://nookkin.com/articles/computer-science/why-computers-use-binary.ndoc

> We only use binary because we currently do not have the technology to
>   create "switches" that can reliably hold more than two possible
>   states. (Quantum computers aren't exactly on sale at the moment.) The
>   binary system was chosen only because it is quite easy to distinguish
>   the presence of an electric current from an absense of electric
>   current, especially when working with trillions of such connections.
>   And using any other number base in this system ridiculous, because the
>   system would need to constantly convert between them. That's all there
>   is to it.

Here's another good read on the subject:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer

---

Your question regarding why 1,000 bytes isn't enough to make 1Kb makes no sense.

1Kb by definition is 1024 bytes.

1Kb is 1024 bytes as supposed to 1000 bytes, because:
1kb = 2^10 bytes = 1024 bytes

Comment: It does make sense. Here is how : 1KB means 1KiloByte. 1 Kilo stands for 10^3. So,1KB means 1000 Bytes. not 1024 bytes. To circumvent the problem new units KibiByte/KiB, MebiBytes/MiB etc was proposed in 1998, but they still aren't widely adopted. 1 Kibi stands 2^10, and 1 KibiByte means 1024 bytes. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)

Comment: I think it's just the way you worded your question. Generally speaking when we use the term 1Kb, it is implied to mean 2^10 bytes, NOT 10^3.  So what it seemed like you were asking was why isn't 1000 bytes enough to store 1024 bytes. However the 2nd part of your question made a LOT more sense,

Answer (score 1):

We human mostly use Decimal Number system for our calculations, this system is based on 10 unique digits ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ), in other words we also call it a base 10 system. In it we can represent any large or small quantity via Power ( Exponent ) of 10.

For example we can write 200 = 2 * 10²

> Therefore In **Decimal System**, it is a usual as well as standard
>   practice to represents or measure different quantities like Kilometer,
>   Kilogram etc in form of power of 10

While, Computer or any electronic machine *currently* use or understand only Binary Number System, this system is based on 2 unique digits only ( 0, 1 ), in other words we also call it a base 2 system. In it we can represent any large or small quantity via Power ( Exponent) of 2.

> Similarly In **Binary System**, it is a usual as well as standard
>   practice to represents or measure different quantities like Kilobyte,
>   Gigabyte etc in form of power of 2

Answer (score 0):

1024 falls on a binary boundary (2 ** 10).